# Copy dynamoDB table Items only to another aws account DynamoDB without S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to transfer all the items in a DynamoDB table from one AWS account(X-Account) (let's call it A-DynamoDB) to another AWS account (Y-Account) (also A-DynamoDB) without utilizing Amazon S3 to store the data. I've come across methods that involve copying tables using Data Pipeline, but they all involve using Amazon S3 as a data storage intermediary.
I want to bypass the S3 step because the table has a significant amount of data, which could lead to delays in both the S3 write and S3 read processes. Instead, I need to directly transfer the table items from one account to another.

Answer (score 2):

As you state significant amount of data I'm going to assume we're talking terrabytes. If both accounts are in the same AWS Organisation you can use [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/create-cross-account-backup.html) which allows you to create a backup and share the backups between the accounts.

Your alternative is [AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb), but using this method you will pay for both the reads from source table and the writes to destination table which could have a significant cost impact in comparison to AWS Backup or the [S3 method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3forDynamoDB.html) using Export/Import feature of DynamoDB.